# How to convert list of string in SQL query WHERE in python?

Tags: python, sql

```
 data=["2001509-00",
"2001523-00",
"2003086-00",
"2003151-00",
"2005530-00",
"2005803-00",
"2005951-00",
"2006928-00",
"2006928R00",
"2007143-01",
"2007340-00",
         ]

Sqlquery='''SELECT * FROM "_SYS_TABLE" WHERE COLUMNNAME IN (''' + ','.join(map(str, data)) + ')'
Sqlquery

It returns string i.e 
'SELECT * FROM "_SYS_TABLE" WHERE COLUMNNAME IN (2001509-00,2001523-00,2003086-00,2003151-00,2005530-00,2005803-00,2005951-00,2006928-00,2006928R00,2007143-01,2007340-00)'
```

I want it to return data in Sqlquery as ('2001509-00','2001523-00','2003086-00'........)

Final result I want is

'SELECT * FROM "_SYS_TABLE" WHERE COLUMNNAME IN ('2001509-00','2001523-00','2003086-00','2003151-00','2005530-00','2005803-00','2005951-00','2006928-00','2006928R00','2007143-01','2007340-00')'

like including '' after and before the list element

Comment: use `f-strings` `f"""SELECT * FROM '_SYS_TABLE' WHERE COLUMNNAME IN ({"','".join(data)})"""` also please don't spam tags use only whats relevant.

Comment: ('2001509-00'','2001523-00','2003086-00','2003151-00','2005530-00','2005803-00','2005951-00','2006928-00','2006928R00','2007143-01','2007340-00)     it returns two '' at the end of first element

Comment: wrap a print around it `print(yoursqlstring)`

Comment: ('2001509-00'','2001523-00','2003086-00','2003151-00','2005530-00','2005803-00','2005951-00','2006928-00','2006928R00','2007143-01','2007340-00)   it shows this , see there is 'firstelement" i need 'firstelement' , there is one extra ' at first element end, and there is no ' at last element end

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
Sqlquery="""SELECT * FROM "_SYS_TABLE" WHERE COLUMNNAME IN ('""" + "','".join(map(str, data)) + "')"
```

Comment: It shows this (\'\'2001509-00\'\',\'2001523-00\',\'2003086-00\',\'2003151-00\',\'2005530-00\',\'2005803-00\',\'2005951-00\',\'2006928-00\',\'2006928R00\',\'2007143-01\',\'2007340-00\')'

Comment: '2001509-00'' at first element is add two ' at the end

Comment: use `print(Sqlquery)`, it will show normally.

Comment: ('2001509-00'','2001523-00','2003086-00','2003151-00','2005530-00','2005803-00','2005951-00','2006928-00','2006928R00','2007143-01','2007340-00) it shows this , see there is 'firstelement" i need 'firstelement' , there is one extra ' at first element end, and there is no ' at last element end

Comment: Did you copy the code? It  displays correctly on my computer. You should not replace the double quotes with single quote.